# RHEL/Centos 6 Cluster multi-site configuration with Pacemaker and split brain situation

Tags: cluster, rhel6, pacemaker

I would configure a 4-nodes cluster using RHEL 6.5 and Pacemaker as reported in the official documentation https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Configuring_the_Red_Hat_High_Availability_Add-On_with_Pacemaker/index.html

The four nodes are splitted on two datacenter, two server in a datacenter and two server in the other.

I want configure a set of KVM virtual machine in HA on this cluster.

The server are connected to a SAN with shared storage between the two datacenter.

The fencing method used for the server is HP iLO(they are HP server).

How can I configure the cluster in order to obtain the quorum between the nodes during a split brain (no network communication between the two datacenter)? Do you have any suggestion or link about a possibile configuration?

I didn't found any reference in the official documentation of redhat related to quorum disk o "Multi-site clusters using ticket" feature of Pacemaker and I can't use two-node cluster configuration because I have 4 nodes in my cluster.

Comment: If you care about your data the cluster should be configured so that is not quorate when a split-brain occurs. Can you tell us which application or type of application you will install on the cluster? Which type of storage will you use? How do you plan to configure fencing?

Comment: I edited the question in order to add also this data.